# Center of Pressure from multi-contact

Tags: mathematical-physics, pressure

What would be the equation of center of pressure, if we put force and torque sensors at 4 wheels of the Car. The force sensor can give output in x,y and z directions; and distance from the center of the car to each tire is also known.

Answer (score 0):

The equation to calculate position of Center of Pressure(CoP) from force and torque sensors and distances is, 
[image]

where,

$M_{ix}$, $M_{iy}$ are the $x$ and $y$ component of Torque Sensor on $i$ wheel respectively.

$F_{iz}$ is the $z$ component of $i$th Force sensor.